# Why is creating a bitcoin fork very difficult and a Ethereum fork easy?

Tags: blockchain-fork

There are a dozen of projects based on Ethereum but very few based on the Bitcoin network. Why is this?

Comment: I'd like to point out that, technically, a fork is as difficult as it is modifying the source code of the project involved. Anyway, what makes a fork successful is the amount of adoption it manages to reach. So, if you want to measure the "difficulty" of a fork in terms of adoption, then we can say bitcoin forks struggle because they're overshadowed by the enormous popularity of bitcoin itself.

Answer (score 1):

Forks of both are equally hard. What you're describing as "Ethereum forks" are actually tokens/smart-contracts that run on the Ethereum network, which isn't very common on Bitcoin (but there's Omni)

EDIT: Remved Rootstock as per darosior's clarification. Its only to relation to Bitcoin is that it uses merged mining, just like Namecoin.

Comment: Rootstock is not on the Bitcoin network.

Comment: @darosior Right, thanks.

Comment: I think it's also useful to mention that the reason why they are some many Ethereum-based tokens is that Ethereum was designed specifically for that purpose.